# How do I bind a property of a control in a UserControl to a property of the Window which contains it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a MainWindow. It contains an instance of UserControl1 with a TextBox. MainWindow also contains an instance of a Settings class. I would like to bind the TextBox to a string property of the Settings class.

The difficulty is UserControl1 has no knowledge of MainWindow or Settings (since I want to use UserControl1 in multiple projects). So I made an interface IString, and I pass that to UserControl1. However, I still can't get any binding to work. I realize I'll have to add INotifyPropertyChanged at some point, but I don't think that's what's preventing it from working here.

```
public interface IString
{
    string String { get; set; }
}

public class Settings : IString
{
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow">
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="TheUserControl"/>
</Window>
```

and codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TheUserControl.Settings = new Settings();
    }
}
```

UserControl1 XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
    <TextBox DataContext="Settings" Text="{Binding String}"/>
</UserControl>
```

and codebehind:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IString Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could read the settings into a proper view model and allow the data context to flow through the window and its children.

Comment: You could make the setting a bindable property and set it when you use the control on MainWindow

Comment: Declare a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties) in your UserControl and bind it to the String property of the Settings class. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40184402/1136211

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is make it so the property in your `UserControl` is bindable from the `MainWindow`. To do this make it a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview). Also, as @Clemens suggested you can add a property chnanged call back to execute other code when your property changes. In addtion you can also set the default property and configure other call backs as well, [see here for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation)

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SettingsProperty 
        = DependencyProperty.Register("Settings", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                "DefaultSetting",
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSettingsChanged)));

    public string Settings
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SettingsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SettingsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnSettingsChanged(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (UserControl1)d;
        var newSettings = (string)e.NewValue;
        //Optionally do something when Settings changed
    }
}
```

Then in the `MainWindow`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow">
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="TheUserControl" Settings="{Binding xyz}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: You should complete this with a PropertyChangedCalback. Otherwise OP will likely add code to the Settings setter, and wonder why it is never called.

Comment: @Clemens great point, edited

Comment: This isn't working for me. Is xyz an instance of Settings or the string property of Settings?

Comment: No `xyz` is whatever you want to bind to, that part you need to fill in.